# Why is day off by 1 and hours is way off on mor ISO 8601 in Moment js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, reactjs, momentjs, iso

With ISO 8601 string, I'm using Moment js and currently doing `moment("2014-05-08T00:20:40Z").format("HH:mm:ss")` to simply get string time of `"00:20:40"`, bu

Comment: The `z` in the timestamp means UTC, so my best guess would be that you aren't in the UTC timezone, so it's formatting the timestamp into your timezone

Answer (score 4):

Your ISO date is a UTC date. That's what the `Z` at the end means. So you are 7 time zones west of UTC.

The time you start with is 20 minutes after midnight on the 8th. If you ran your code in Paris, France, you'd get the right answer (ignoring "summer time" adjustment). However, since you're 7 time zones west, you get 5:20 in the afternoon, and you're still in the previous calendar day.

By one way of looking at things, there's nothing to "fix". The local time version based on where you are represents the same point in time as the original ISO UTC time. Everything is working properly; the default representation of date values is in *local* time. The Date primitive object in JavaScript has APIs to access the components in UTC terms if you want to go that way.

You can use `.toISOString()` if you want to get the original ISO string back:

```
moment("2014-05-08T00:20:40Z").toISOString()
```

Or, you can include a time zone tag in your format string:

```
moment("2014-05-08T00:20:40Z").format("HH:mm:ss zz")
```

(Note that the "z" in the format string doesn't mean the same thing as the "Z" in the ISO time. It's just the formatting special character, from the first letter of the word "zone".  In the ISO string, it's the first letter of the word "zero", and it means that the time is at zero offset from UTC time. Some people call it "Zulu Time" because of that "Z".)

Comment: Correct, but see also: https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/. Alternately, you may need to use the correct factory function for your use case.

Comment: @MaggiePint that's a great article; it's always hard to tell in SO question like these what the larger context is. Where did that ISO UTC date come from in the first place, for example? It could be that the simplest solution here would be to ammend the formatting on the server. And even then, it depends on application semantics. Anyway thanks, that's good stuff and I'll try to remember to link to it (as you said, these come up all the time!).